# Any minimal source code to measure network latency (client server program)

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, latency, low-latency

I want to measure latency across two Linux boxes connected directly via a 10 gig optical fibre. Basically I want to measure RTT latency after a packet sent has been received back on the same machine. So basically client will send a packet to server and take the current time, server will return the packet back to client and second time stamp will be taken once the packet is received. Total latency will be difference of two time stamp.

I would like to meausure latency for both UDP and TCP protocols.

I have tried using **sockperf** and it claims doing similar things but I want something very simple one file code which I can use for bench-marking while understanding fully.

Can you share any links of simple program to do this? Please not my interest is in only latensy and not in throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Sync the time in the two Linux box. Form a data buffer , filling the time stamp in the header & dummy data in the payload. Then send the data over the TCP/UDP socket to the other end & echo the data from the other end. Calculate the elapsed time from the header time stamp which would give you the accurate RTT.